# UICloudSharingController error: recordChangeTag specified, but record not found

Tags: swift, core-data, cloudkit

I'm using `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` for storing data and `UICloudSharingController` for sharing.

Here's how `UICloudSharingController` is created (that's pretty basic stuff):

```
    func share(_ record: Record, avatar: UIImage) {
        let controller = shareControllerForRecord(record, avatar: avatar)
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        controller.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = []
        present(controller, animated: true)
    }

    func shareControllerForRecord(_ record: Record, avatar: UIImage) -> UICloudSharingController {

        if let share = share(for: record) {
            let controller = UICloudSharingController(share: share, container: self.cloudKitContainer)
            return controller
        } else {
            let controller = UICloudSharingController { [weak self] (controller, completion: @escaping (CKShare?, CKContainer?, Error?) -> Void) in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.persistentContainer.share([record], to: nil) { objectIDs, share, container, error in
                    if let share = share {
                        record.managedObjectContext?.performAndWait {
                            share[CKShare.SystemFieldKey.title] = record.title
                            share[CKShare.SystemFieldKey.thumbnailImageData] = avatar.pngData()
                        }
                    }
                    completion(share, container, error)
                }
            }

            return controller
        }
    }
```

Once `UICloudSharingController` is created the user do basic stuff, and in most cases sharing works fine. But some users (I can see it in analytics) get this error:

> Error Domain=_UIShareErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x28399e340 {Error Domain=CKErrorDomain Code=2 "CKInternalErrorDomain: 1011" UserInfo={ContainerID=iCloud.net.bundleidentifier, NSDebugDescription=CKInternalErrorDomain: 1011, CKPartialErrors={ "<CKRecordID: 0x2837f2280; recordName=cloudkit.zoneshare, zoneID=com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.share.9A2156CD-2E69-4987-966E-AC5A3F593737:*defaultOwner*>" = "<CKError 0x28399d890: "Unknown Item" (11/2003); server message = "recordChangeTag specified, but record not found"; op = CE76405043B1BE49; uuid = C567647F-331B-4002-9893-2791F38131B3; container ID = "iCloud.net.bundleidentifier">"; }, RequestUUID=C567647F-331B-4002-9893-2791F38131B3, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to modify some records, CKErrorDescription=Failed to modify some records, NSUnderlyingError=0x28399e430 {Error Domain=CKInternalErrorDomain Code=1011 "Failed to modify some records"

For me it seems like remote database doesn't have the Record uploaded yet. But it's strange, because these are not newly created records. Besides, for majority of users sharing works.
Can anyone advise?

Comment: I'm getting the similar error. I'm not using Coredata though. It doesn't work when we share using Apple Mail app. If you share using Messages, Gmail or Invite with link it seems to work. This started happening only after iOS 16.

Comment: I didn't solve it either... I had bunch of other issues with iOS 16 so I got rid of UICloudSharingController and implemented sharing with pure CloudKit. No issues so far.

Comment: How do you share a record without UICloudSharingController?